# How to wait for popBackStack to complete?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to go back to the dashboard fragment, but it looks like at this point **currentFragment** is returning the fragment it was before **popBackStack** was called. Apparently there is some delay. The question is how to wait exactly that long for **currentFragment** to return a **DashboardFragment**?

I am using single activity with jetpack navigation.

the code from activity:

```
navController?.popBackStack(R.id.dashboard_fragment, false)
val dashboardFragment = (currentFragment as? DashboardFragment)
```

currentFragment property is

```
val currentFragment: Fragment? get() = supportFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is NavHostFragment }?.childFragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment
```

the same result if I use

```
... childFragmentManager?.fragments?.first()
```

All I need is an instance of the fragment to which I am returning, perhaps there are other ways to achieve this...

Comment: use PopBackStackImmediate

Comment: This seems like it could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @HenryTwist I want to call a method from this fragment, with the intent that is available in the function scope (onNewIntent) where I called the popBackStack(). This is necessary for processing deep links.

Comment: @DominikWuttke, it would be nice solution, but there is no such method for Navigation, and the fragment manager contains only the current fragment